# Enum, String или что-то другое?

Tags: java, архитектура, code-style

Представим следующую ситацию: пользователь делает в **UI** выбор из какого-то списка, например, пусть это будет список языков.
Для каждого языка существует какой-то свой набор данных и классов, который нужно использовать, т.е. существует соответствие

- язык_1 — набор_1
- язык_2 — набор_2
- ...
- язык_n — набор_n

Каким образом лучше определять соответствующий набор, учитывая, что список доступных языков хоть и не супер часто, но может меняться?

Создать какой-то `enum Language { язык_1, язык_2, ...}` в котором при необходимости просто добавлять/удалять языки? и потом использовать его в разных местах, например, через `switch` / `Map<Language, Набор (или Часть набора)>`

Или в таких случаях лучше использовать просто String: для каждого языка своё, заранее определённое название, которое обязуются не менять (по сути получится некий аналог Enum)?

Возможно есть какие-то более удачные подходы?

**P.S.**

возможно я слегка запутал излишними подробностями, поэтому ещё раз краткая суть моего вопроса:

что лучше использовать в подобных ситуациях `enum`, `String` или вовсе какое-то иное решение?

Comment: Может меняться пользователем?

Comment: @digital-mag нет, разработчиками, например добавили поддержку языка ЯзыкААА

Comment: поставившему минус и голосонувшему за закрытие, что по-вашему не так? что в вопросе конкретизировать?

Comment: Ну в общем-то если список задается на этапе разработки, то на мой взгляд нет особой разницы. Но enum, пожалуй, будет проще рефакторить

Comment: Если может меняться, то енам же не подходит? Стринг будет нарушать принцип инкапсуляции. Лучше отдельный класс, сделать его иммутабельным и использовать.

Comment: @SergeyZh. не уверен, что правильно понял, под отдельным классом вы подразумеваете просто обёртку над String или класс для **языка**? Можете подробнее объяснить?

Comment: @timbars Это класс для языка, но если он будет включать только стринг поля, то можно сказать, что это обёртка над стрингом

Comment: @SergeyZh. и как вы предлагаете использовать такой класс? мне в любом случае надо этот класс на основе чего-то инстанцировать (или выбирать, если уже существуют объекты для каждого языка). А выбор я делаю на основе ввода пользователя, тем самым возвращаясь к вопросу о String vs Enum для совершения этого самого выбора. Или я что-то не понимаю в вашем предложении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключевой вопрос здесь, каким образом происходит добавление нового языка? А именно, требует ли это нового релиза приложения, т.е. есть ли изменения в коде или только в конфигурации и/или данных?

Если добавление нового языка требует изменения в коде, как-то добавления этих самых наборов и/или добавление кода в switch или конфигурации нового языка в map-ах, то тогда добавление нового значения в enum - это не проблема, и лучше использовать enum.

Если же добавление нового языка не требует изменения в коде, а достигается только изменением конфигурации приложения, то лучше использовать immutable обертку вокруг `String` (для контроля типов) реализуя value object, который по сути будет работать как enum (включая метод типа `valueOf`), с той лишь разницей, что значения в нем произвольные:

```
public final class Language {
  // можно так добавить какие-то фиксированные значения, если нужно
  public static final Language ENGLISH = Language.valueOf("en");
  public static final Language GERMAN = Language.valueOf("de");

  private final String value;

  private Language(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static Language valueOf(String value) {
    return new Language(value);
  }

  // тут определить equals и hashCode на основе value
  ...
}

Map<Language, DevKit> map = ...;

Language language = Language.valueOf(langFromUserInput);
DevKit devKit = map.get(language);
// используем devKit
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Ещё небольшой вопросик не совсем по теме: как думаете, лучше возвращать с уровня **UI** `langFromUserInput` или же сразу `Language`?

Comment: Не знаю что у вас в качестве UI, сам UI тоже имеет какую-то структуру и т.д. Очень возможно что и в UI не нужно держать строку, а пользоваться `Language`. Вы же не даете пользователю вводить вручную строку? Он вероятно выбирает из списка? А значит и там можно, точнее нужно, держать список `Language`.

Comment: логично, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вариант со словарем нормальный. Могу добавить, что с точки зрения ООП, можно выделить "Набор" в отдельный класс, где будете хранить все, что вам нужно.

```
public class DevKit {
    private List<String> classes;
    private List<String> libraries;
    
    // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

Тогда `Map<>` будет выглядеть так

```
Map<String, DevKit> map = new HashMap<String, DevKit>();
```

Comment: Спасибо, но вопрос не про использование Map/switch и не про выделение Набора в отдельный класс, а про то, что лучше использовать: `enum`, `String` или вовсе какое-то 3-е решение

Comment: @timbars На самом деле принципиальной разницы нет, используйте то, с чем удобнее работать. Лично я предпочел бы `String`, потому что предполагаю, что инфа о языках будет подгружаться с JSON файла, в котором будет поле "languageName", а оно соответственно `String`. Если все это вручную заполняется (что не очень хорошо), то скорее всего использовал бы `enum`